# Explode not working for section symbol "§"

Tags: php

I have a string that is being returned from a MSSQL database that is delimited by section signs "§" I need to split this at each section sign however explode will not work in this case. Could this be something to do with character encoding?

```
$stringFromDB = "259354§261016§266618";
$stringArray = explode("§", $stringFromDB);
```

This should give me an array with 3 items however, the section signs are not matched in the database string (even though they are there) so, the explode does not work. If I echo() the contents of $stringFromDB, the section signs are there. I have also tried to replace the section signs with str_replace() and this does not work either! This makes no sense!

Comment: When you use the explode function, the actual delimiters are removed. This is the expected behavior.

Comment: -1 http://codepad.org/7pjFgzn9 Works.

Comment: Yes, I understand how the explode function works.

Comment: @user1017477 - then I'm afraid I don't really understand what your question is. Could you please try to rephrase?

Comment: see my comment below, I mean the section signs are not found in the original string so nothing is exploded!!!!!!!!!

Comment: So you don't have `a string that is being returned from a MSSQL database that is delimited by section signs "§"`? You should clarify your question and if it is related to database retrieval, you should post the relevant code of that section.

Comment: Have you tried to make sure the § you get from the DB is indeed the same as you have in your code? (e.g. copy/paste from an example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the encoding of the .php file causing the section signs to not match. Once I changed the file's encoding type the script now works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

`explode()` doesn't preserve what you're "exploding" on. If you want the symbols preserved, then use `preg_split()` instead:

```
$stringArray = preg_split("/§/", $stringFromDB, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE );
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I do not want the symbols preserved, I just want them matched! For whatever reason on this server, in this script, it will not work! That is my problem. The string can be printed and the symbols are there however, $strArray = explode("§", "259354§261016§266618"); and then echo(count($strArray)); outputs 1!!! This makes no sense!!!

Comment: well, different charsets then. the `§` you're getting from the DB may not be the same `§` that you typed into your code. maybe it's been htmlentity-encoded and it's really `&para;` in the DB. this would be especially true if you're doing your debugging via browser - remember that the browser will **RENDER** any html/entities it finds, and will essentially be LYING to you about what's really in the text.